# SQL Server stored procedure select, exists, multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, stored-procedures

Any method to do this?

**Table1**

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

**Table2**

```
 3 (with the condition)
 4 (without the condition)
```

**I want to:**

1. Select all records from Table1 if it exists in Table 2, where...(condition)
2. Select all records from Table1 if it not exists in Table2
3. Combine both select results. Sort all results with their created date.

For example, the result should be:

**Result**

```
 1
 2
 3
 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all responses.

I come out with the answer I want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
                              WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
                              AND t2.CIF_KEY = @CifKey
                              AND t2.STATUS <> ''3'')
    AND (condition in where clause)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE condition OR t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.CreatedDate;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03a84/14) (I assumed condition to be `t2.id!=4`, but it can be anything else depending on other data in your tables).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help.

```
SELECT t1.* from table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.ID

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.* from table1 t1 where ID in
(
     SELECT t2.ID from table1 t1 except Select t2.ID from table2 t2
)

ORDER BY t1.CreatedDate
```

Comment: 1 - You forgot the condition. 2 - `SELECT t2.ID from table1 t1` will fail. 3 - Why `IN (... t1 EXCEPT ... t2)` instead of `NOT IN (... t2)` ? 4 - The performance is not great ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03a84/7), look at the execution plans).

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple solution. 
One way 
    we can get the result set using two different queries and at last combine both of the result-set using UNION

Another way, 
   First statement is saying that get all the result set from TABLE1 if it exists in TABLE2 as well with some criteria (condition in where clause)
         means using INNER JOIN we can achieve this
   Second statement is saying get all the result set from TABLE1 which are not present in TABLE2 
         means along with INNER JOIN ed query also include the TABLE1's data if not present in TABLE2
         here we can take the help of LEFT OUTER JOIN (taking TABLE1 on the left side)

Assumption: (condition: t1.Id != 4)

Let's try to understand the query using both of the above mentioned ways

```
---- -- --Step1  Create table and insert records
---- create table1 with Id int identity columsn
--CREATE TABLE Table1 (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), CreatedDate smalldatetime default(getdate()));
--go
---- insert 1st 5 integers into Table1
--INSERT INTO Table1 DEFAULT VALUES 
--go 5

---- create Table2 with Id int column
--CREATE TABLE Table2 (Id INT , CreatedDate smalldatetime default(getdate()));
--go
---- insert records 3,5 into Table2
--INSERT INTO Table2(Id) VALUES (3), (4);

-- -- -- Solution: one way
; WITH cteMyFirstResult AS 
(
    -- 2.1. Select all records from Table1 if it exists in Table 2, where...(condition)
    SELECT
        Id,     CreatedDate
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    WHERE t1.Id IN (SELECT Id   FROM Table2 AS t2)
    AND t1.Id != 4  -- assumption it can be any condition
),cteMySecondResult AS (
    -- 2.2. Select all records from Table1 if it not exists in Table2
    SELECT
        Id,     CreatedDate
    FROM Table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 AS t2)
)
    -- 2.3. Combine both select results. Sort all results with their created date.
    SELECT
        Id, CreatedDate
    FROM cteMyFirstResult 
UNION
    SELECT
        Id, CreatedDate
    FROM cteMySecondResult
    ORDER BY CreatedDate;
```

-- -- Solution: Another way (with bug)

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.CreatedDate
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.Id != 4 
Order by T1.CreatedDate;
```

-- in this query we are using the criteria after doing the join operation. 
-- thus after filtering out the result set based on JOIN Condition this condition will get applied 
-- and if there is any null record in the Table1 for column Id (used in join) will not come in the final result-set

-- to avoid this we can include NULL check along with our criteria

-- -- Solution: Another way

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.CreatedDate
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE ( t1.Id != 4 )  OR t1.Id IS NULL  -- include all your criteria within small-barcket)
Order by T1.CreatedDate;
```